# Invoking rest service with sql.timestamp variable in model object for @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I know how to make the code below run if I change the variable firstDT from Timestamp to String and then convert from Timestamp to String and vice-verse inside of the get and set method. I would like to know if it is possible to make the model below works with a Timestamp variable.

```
//Client:
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/my_app/log/Mas60010");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "";

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("subCd", "A");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
map.put("firstDT", "/Date(" + format.format(new Date()) + ")/");

map.put("messageFormat", "AFMAMXAS2CAPCISIMFMDSQSTSTRVIS");

json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);

StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
input.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

//Rest Web Service:
@RequestMapping(value="Mas60010", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getFirst(@RequestBody Mas60010 mas60010) {
    return "I only reach here if firstDT is String ";
}

//Model
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class Mas60010 {
       private String subCd;
       private Timestamp firstDT; // the doubt root is here
       private String messageFormat;
       public String getSubCd() {
              return subCd;
       }

       public void setSubCd(String subCd) {
              this.subCd = subCd;
       }

       public Timestamp getFirstDT() {
              return firstDT;
       }

       public void setFirstDT(Timestamp firstDT) {
              this.firstDT = firstDT;
       }

       public String getMessageFormat() {
              return messageFormat;
       }

       public void setMessageFormat(String messageFormat) {
              this.messageFormat = messageFormat;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
         return "ok";
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi I am still looking for answer to this question.

Comment: No one can  help me in this question?

Comment: HI.. Did you find solution for this.. i am also facing the same issue. your solution will help me . please share..

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question specifically but I just tried to do a REST call with an object that has a field variable with a type of `java.sql.Timestamp`. I was able to solve this by using its super class `java.util.Date` instead. The reason it did not work is that `Timestamp` does not have an empty constructor and `Date`does.